# Photoshop 6.0 stopped working on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, adobe-photoshop, photoshop-6

Starting fails with this message:

> Unable to continue because of a hardware or system error. Sorry, but
> this error is unrecoverable.

[image]

Comment: It is likely that your preferences got somehow screwed up. Just holding CTRL-SHIFT while the program launches restores your preferences, and that is usually enough to get it working normally again. Enabling compatibility as in your answer basically also makes it load another profile

Comment: Oh, wait, this is not about CS6 but the older 6. Never mind. Leaving the comment for those who are using CS6 or CS5 for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

Run the program in compatibility mode "Windows 98 / Windows Me".

Based on these [Adobe](https://feedback.photoshop.com/conversations/photoshop/photoshop-6-unable-to-continue-because-of-a-hardware-or-system-error-sorry-but-this-error-is-unrecoverable/5f5f46234b561a3d42758fd2) and [Microsoft](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/photoshop-6-and-windows-10/d14fc38f-7693-41d4-8bc8-6ff37910570b) forum threads.

[image]